# Changing number of ticks in a midi file

Tags: midi

I am working on visualizations of 3 midi files that I would like to compare with one another (all 3 have a tempo of 120BPM). For the x axis of my visualization I am using the noteON and noteOFF ticks within each file. However, each file/work assigns a different amount of ticks to what is a quarter note, half note, etc. on the music score. Is there a way to "normalize" the files, so that in every file the same amount of ticks corresponds to the same duration on the score? I changed the PPQ resolutions and gave them the same value - in case this would help - but it didn't.

I am new to midi, so any contribution or hint on whether the above is possible would be helpful.

Comment: What software(s) are you using for this?

Comment: I'd open them all in pretty much any MIDI sequencer, then save back out again as new MIDI files. That will, in effect, 'rationalise' them all to be not only the same ppq but also other data structures, running status etc would get remodelled into all the same type.

Comment: @music2myear I am using Processing for the visualization. I changed the PPQ resolutions in Sublime (hex value in header).

Comment: @Tetsujin could you suggest any freely available sequencers for Mac? I am using the java sequencer (javax.sound.midi) within Processing for visualization, but I don't know how I can change the midi files there, so that they use the same time resolution..

Comment: tbh, I don't have any recommendation. I've been using Cubase since forever [since before Mac v1 in the 90s], so freeware isn't something I've ever investigated.